# How many JVM process executed in application server if we have thousands of concurrent users in application

Tags: java, performance, tomcat, weblogic

Suppose i have my application in weblogic server and it is being used by thousand of users. How many JVM will run that time? is JVM is shared by all users or seperate jvm process is created for all users?

On which factor it depends?

Comment: That completely depends on your server's configuration, available resource on machine, type of your application and so on. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24432/self_tuned.htm#CNFGD112

Comment: I've never heard about "process per user". Someone might be doing this, but given that a JVM is a pretty big process needing quite some time to start, it makes little sense. At the same time, handling thousands of users in a single JVM works well.

Answer (score 0):

*How many* ***JVM process** executed in application server if we have thousands of **concurrent users** in application*

I highlighted the 2 phrases that are to be noticed in your question.

**JVM Process** - Any Java application runs as a JVM Process. Within the process, it spawns N number of threads depending on the thread pool configuration. Thread pool count can be configured at JVM configuration level or at application level.

**Concurrent Users -** Each Concurrent User request translates to concurrent connections to the application server. Mapping between connection and threads are not 1:1. For example, 10,000 Users may hit your application concurrently but it does not always mean, it will create 10,000 threads. That is why you have a concept called Thread Pool. So, every time, application server receives a new connection, it allocates the task to one of the available threads to do the job

Hope this explains. Please let us know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks much Prem for the explanation. Many doubts are cleared. Thank you again